# Camel CXF Response Message to caller - Duplicate WS-Security Parts

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf

I have a Camel CxfEndpoint Service defined. The Reception of the messages works fine, but the Response/Acknowledgement Message I am producing has a problem. The WS-Security parts/actions in the message are left in and therefore in the response I have my own WS-Security Parts (Signature Timestamp) plus the WS-Security Parts from the caller/original message.
The Message Acknowledgement is not accepted from the original caller and I suspect that this is the problem (that I have their Signature wth BinarySecuritySessionToken and our own).

The Camel route is rather simple for trying to resolve the issue:

```
from("myEndpoint")
    .transacted()
    .process(new PreProcessor())
    .to("mock:end")
```

I have defined the Camel CxfEndpoint in the route as:

```
CxfEndpoint cxfEndpoint = new CxfEndpoint();
cxfEndpoint.setAddress("http://0.0.0.0:8888/services/Service");
cxfEndpoint.setWsdlURL("Service.wsdl");
cxfEndpoint.setCamelContext(camelContext);
....
```

Problem example Timestamp:

```
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-6757512FE17DCDC903153191998160526">                                   
  <wsu:Created>2018-07-18T13:19:41.605Z</wsu:Created>
  <wsu:Expires>2018-07-18T13:24:41.605Z</wsu:Expires>                                           
</wsu:Timestamp>
<u:Timestamp xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" u:Id="uuid-b2a1c0b2-8263-4afc-bc99-f8a46da80ce7-693">
  <u:Created>2018-07-18T13:19:42.905Z</u:Created>
  <u:Expires>2018-07-18T13:24:42.905Z</u:Expires>
</u:Timestamp>
```

The general structure of the response message seems to be fine, but I need to strip the WS-Security Action Parts from the message.
Is there a way to strip these parts or do I need to construct a entirely new message?
Please let me know if you need additional information, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it by adding another Interceptor for removing the Security Header.
I would like to know if this is a acceptable approach or if there is a better solution to this problem.

```
public class RemoveSecurityHeadersOutInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor
{    
  public RemoveSecurityHeadersOutInterceptor(String phase) {
    super(Phase.PRE_PROTOCOL);
  }

public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault
{
  List<Header> headers = message.getHeaders(); 
  headers.removeIf(h -> h.getName().getLocalPart().equals("Security"));
  }
}
```